# Establish the equivalence of two inverse trigonometric function based formulas

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, physics, trigonometry

In a comment to

[3D5D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230856/evaluate-3d-and-5d-constrained-integrals-for-absolute-separability-probabilitie)

user JimB provided an answer to the question posed there of finding the "two-quater[nionic]bit" absolute separability Hilbert-Schmidt probability. (Previously, in [TwoQubit](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral),
he had obtained the "two-qubit" counterpart.)

The answer now took the form

```
327574875999612773528659/95105071448064 - 2951081236201839/(524288 Sqrt[2]) - (15390446918294583135 \[Pi])/(17179869184 Sqrt[2]) + (15390446918294583135 ArcCsc[18/Sqrt[50 + 17 Sqrt[2]]])/(2147483648 Sqrt[2])
```

An earlier answer,

```
-((13 (-216449750678398795533760757497856 + 
   176860737736399592490919645937664 Sqrt[2] + 
   279292548969739228073088142369304501839785 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] - 
   558572941247617043110461841280869072896000 Sqrt[2]
     ArcCot[Sqrt[2]] + 
   23637916932187025487103667523337320 Sqrt[2]
     ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]] - 
   16178155879591789043088455851252390200 Sqrt[2]
     ArcCot[3 + Sqrt[2]] - 
   558589165778586158484606527963549721006600 Sqrt[2]
     ArcTan[Sqrt[2]]))/816946343106356485029888)
```

of somewhat different form, to the very same question had been provided in eq. (36) in

[2009paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0393044008001381#b34)

Both formulas above evaluate (N[,50]) to

```
0.000039870347068019928855365404975780992652117606213067
```

However, the FullSimplify command does not reveal the formulas' evident equivalence.

It might seem that some inverse trigonometric function transformations would be required to accomplish that.

So, can the evident equivalence of the two formulas be formally established employing Mathematica?

Comment: `Block[{$MaxExtraPrecision = 1000}, ans1 - ans2 // N[#, 1000] &] ` is close enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

`FindIntegerNullVector` is your friend. Notice that this method allows you to obtain an even simpler expression.

**A. Find relations between sets of different functions**

```
v[1]={ArcCsc[18/Sqrt[50+17 Sqrt[2]]],ArcTan[Sqrt[2]],ArcCot[3+Sqrt[2]]};
v[2]={ArcCot[Sqrt[2]],ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]],ArcCot[3+Sqrt[2]]};
v[3]={ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]],ArcCot[Sqrt[2]],ArcTan[Sqrt[2]]};
v[4]={ArcCot[Sqrt[2]],ArcTan[Sqrt[2]],π/2};
```

**B. This is the main part**

```
Table[FindIntegerNullVector[N[v[i],1000]],{i,4}]
Out[1]= {{-3,-1,11},{-2,1,4},{1,1,-1},{1,1,-1}}
```

**C. Make a list of replacement rules**

```
r[1]={ArcCsc[18/Sqrt[50+17 Sqrt[2]]]->(-ArcTan[Sqrt[2]]+11ArcCot[3+Sqrt[2]])/3};
r[2]={ArcCot[3+Sqrt[2]]->1/4(2ArcCot[Sqrt[2]]-ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]])};
r[3]={ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]]->ArcTan[Sqrt[2]]-ArcCot[Sqrt[2]]};
r[4]={ArcCot[Sqrt[2]]->π/2-ArcTan[Sqrt[2]]};
```

**D. Apply the rules**

```
sx=Fold[ReplaceAll,x,Array[r,4]]//Expand;
sy=Fold[ReplaceAll,y,Array[r,4]]//Expand;
sx-sy
Out[2]= 0
```

### Comment/observation

In principle, all but one identities found by the [LLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) method are easy to prove by hand. Only the first one, namely
$$11\,\mathrm{arccot}\big(3+\sqrt{2}\big) = \mathrm{arctan}\big(\sqrt{2}\big)+ 3\,\mathrm{arccsc}\!\Bigg\{\frac{18}{\sqrt{50+17 \sqrt{2}}}\Bigg\}$$
is somewhat unexpected.

Comment: Interesting and impressive! Didn't know of the FindIntegerNullVector command. To what does "LLL method" refer?

Comment: @PaulB.Slater LLL is the [Lenstra–Lenstra–Lovász lattice basis reduction algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra–Lenstra–Lovász_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm). In Mathematica it is implemented in the `LatticeReduce` command, and `FindIntegerNullVector` is using it.

Comment: Very nice!  In a related question of @PaulB.Slater the quantity $\phi=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ held a sacred place.  Using `FindIntegerNullVector[N[{ArcTan[Sqrt[2]], \[Pi], ArcCos[1/3]}, 1000]]` one can construct the rule `ArcTan[Sqrt[2]] -> (\[Pi] - \[Phi])/2` resulting in another equal representation:  $\frac{15390446918294583135 \phi }{1073741824 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{327574875999612773528659}{95105071448064}-\frac{2951081236201839}{524288 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{46171340754883749405 \pi }{8589934592 \sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: @JimB That is probably the most economical way of writing it, nice!

Comment: What can be done with this formula -((3840 (-5358569267936 + 33756573946095 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] - 
       270052591568760 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[Sqrt[2]] + 
       11149704525960 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]] + 
       270052591568760 Sqrt[2]
         ArcCot[3 + Sqrt[2]]))/(-1959684729929728 + 
     1601255307608064 Sqrt[2] + 1529087492782080 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] - 
     45247615492565918250 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[Sqrt[2]] + 
     22619730179635540245 Sqrt[2] ArcSec[3]))?  It's from eq. (35) in the 2009 paper and is claimed there to be the Hilbert-Schmidt area/volume ratio for the absolutely separable two-qubit states.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater If you think this question is closely related to the OP, please update it and I will be happy to try some approaches in my arsenal. If it is only tangentially related, please, post it as a new question.

Comment: OK, yarchik. Will mull over how to further proceed. Since the formula under discussion directly pertains to "two-qubit" states, and not "two-quarter[nionic] states", it's more strictly in the domain of the earlier question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral

Comment: @PaulB.Slater Yes, please think how to better formulate the question. In the current form "What can be done with this formula ...?" it lacks concreteness. You have to say in which direction you want to steer.

Comment: Well, I guess what my "What can be done with this formula ...?" question was asking for some possible simplification/condensation, along the lines of what had already been achieved. But, in any case, I'm on the verge of formulating/posting a new question on these matters.

Comment: @PaulB.Slater By the way, I looked at the formula in one of your comments, it is not syntactically correct, what is `Sqrt[2] [Pi] `? Anyway, please let me know if you find my answer to your OP unsatisfactory in some ways.

Comment: Per the comment of yarchik, the two [Pi]'s in the formula of mine in the comment above should simply be Pi. In any case, the corrected formula was successfully dealt with/simplified in https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231268/confirm-and-possibly-simplify-a-2009-result-for-a-2d-constrained-integration along the lines you developed. Now posting an answer to https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231268/confirm-and-possibly-simplify-a-2009-result-for-a-2d-constrained-integration possibly needing further application of your FindIntegerNullVector-based approach.