# Confirm and possibly simplify a 2009 result for a 2D constrained integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, probability-or-statistics, physics, boolean-computation, constraint

This is a direct descendant of two other recent questions,
[3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral) and [Equivalence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231201/establish-the-equivalence-of-two-inverse-trigonometric-function-based-formulas),
both of which have been
answered in skillful, interesting manners. (See also the comment [actually answer] of JimB to
[3D5D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230856/evaluate-3d-and-5d-constrained-integrals-for-absolute-separability-probabilitie), applying the methodology of [3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral) to a higher-order problem.)

We would now like to turn the focus from the 3D constrained integration problem posed at the very outset in [3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral) to a 2D one, by modifying the constraint (for absolute separability) there

```
Boole[Subscript[λ, 1] > Subscript[λ, 2] && Subscript[λ, 2] > Subscript[λ, 3] && Subscript[λ, 3] > 1 - Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, 3] && Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 3] < 2 Sqrt[Subscript[λ, 2] (1 - Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, 3])]]
```

so that the inequality

```
Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 3] < 2 Sqrt[Subscript[λ, 2] (1 - Subscript[λ, 1] Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, 3]
```

becomes an equality

```
Subscript[λ, 1] - Subscript[λ, 3] ==2 Sqrt[Subscript[λ, 2] (1 - Subscript[λ, 1] Subscript[λ, 2] - Subscript[λ, 3]
```

The resultant 2D integration (formulation given at end of question) should yield the Hilbert-Schmidt probability that a "two-qubit" state lies on the boundary of the absolutely separable states, rather than as in the 3D formulation within the volume of such states.

Now, relatedly, in eq. (35) of [2009paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0393044008001381#b34)
the inverse trigonometric function based formula ($\approx 20.9648519$)

```
-((3840 (-5358569267936 + 33756573946095 Sqrt[2] [Pi] - 270052591568760 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[Sqrt[2]] + 11149704525960 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]] + 270052591568760 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[3 + Sqrt[2]]))/(-1959684729929728 + 1601255307608064 Sqrt[2] + 1529087492782080 Sqrt[2] [Pi] - 45247615492565918250 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[Sqrt[2]] + 22619730179635540245 Sqrt[2] ArcSec[3]))
```

was given for the Hilbert-Schmidt area-volume ratio of the two-qubit absolutely separable states.

Now, I would like to ask, first, whether this formula can be condensed/simplified, possibly along the lines of that employed by the user yarchik in the answer to [Equivalence](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231201/establish-the-equivalence-of-two-inverse-trigonometric-function-based-formulas), in which the FindIntegerNullVector command was employed.

Secondly, I would like to ask if the area-to-volume ratio formula  could itself be rederived by solving the 2D constrained integration problem indicated at the beginning of this question--followed by the scaling of its result by the answer of JimB

`29902415923/497664 - 50274109/(512 Sqrt[2]) - (3072529845 π)/(32768 Sqrt[2]) +(1024176615 ArcCos[1/3])/(4096 Sqrt[2])`

given in [3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral)  for the absolute separability Hilbert-Schmidt probability for the two-qubit states.

We must note, though, that the original 3D constrained integration problem posed  in [3D](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230127/evaluate-a-certain-three-dimensional-constrained-integral) was solved  there in an unconstrained form, employing a change-of-variables

```
change = {Subscript[λ, 1] -> x/(1 + 2 x), Subscript[λ, 2] -> y/(1 + y) (1 + x)/(1 + 2 x), Subscript[λ, 3] -> z 1/(1 + y) (1 + x)/(1 + 2 x)};
```

just recently provided by N. Tessore. This  transformed the problem into

```
Integrate[integrand2, {z, 1/2, 1}, {y, z, 2 + 2 Sqrt[1 - z] - z}, {x, y, 2 Sqrt[-((-y - 2 y^2 - y^3 + y z + 2 y^2 z + y^3 z)/(-1 + y + z)^4)] + ( 4 y + z - 3 y z - z^2)/(-1 + y + z)^2}],
```

where

```
integrand2 = (9081072000 (1 + x)^8 (x - y)^2 (1 - 2 z)^2 (y - z)^2 (-1 + y + z)^2 (z + x (-1 - y + z))^2 (-1 + z + x (y + z))^2)/((1 + 2 x)^16 (1 + y)^15)  .
```

The question of what would be a suitable change-of-variables in the requested dimension reduction scenario seems of interest.

---

In his comment to the originally-posed question, JimB simplified (LeafCount 55 vs. 96) the area-volume ratio given above to

```
-((15 (-1339642316984 + 1393713065745 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] - 
2787426131490 Sqrt[2] ArcCos[1/3]))/(2 (-956877309536 + 781862943168 Sqrt[2] + 746624752335 Sqrt[2] \[Pi] - 1990999339560 Sqrt[2] ArcCos[1/3])))
```

As noted in my comment in response to that of JimB, I observed that FullSimplify applied to the product of this result and the earlier one of his (given above)

```
`29902415923/497664 - 50274109/(512 Sqrt[2]) - (3072529845 π)/(32768 Sqrt[2]) +(1024176615 ArcCos[1/3])/(4096 Sqrt[2])`
```

gives us simply

```
 (5 (-669821158492 + 1393713065745 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]]))/5308416 ≈0.0766949
```

which I now conjecture should be the result of the requested 2D integration. This integration problem is expressible as
({Subscript[[Lambda], 1] -> x, Subscript[[Lambda], 2] -> y,
Subscript[[Lambda], 3] -> z}) in the form

```
Integrate[9081072000 (x - y)^2 (1 - 3 x + 3 y - 4 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 (1 - 3 x +
 y - 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 (2 y - 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 (-1 + 2 x + 
2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 (x - 3 y + 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 Boole[x > y && 3 y > x + 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y] && 
3 x + 4 Sqrt[y - 2 x y] > 1 + 3 y], {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}].
```

The transformation {z -> x - 2 y + 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y]} was used to reduce the original 3D problem to the 2D one.

---

---

In a series of three consecutive comments to the answer `(956877309536 + 243 Sqrt[2] (-3217542976 + 1024176615 ArcCos[5983/6561])))/2654208` given by yarchik, I indicated that the alternative (seemingly superior) use of the transformation  {y -> 1/2 (1 - x - z + Sqrt[1 - 2 x - 2 z + 4 x z])}
yields a result

```
(5 (-1339642316984 + 1393713065745 Sqrt[2] ArcTan[(4 Sqrt[2])/7]))/5308416
```

apparently exactly twice the conjecture `(5 (-669821158492 + 1393713065745 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]]))/5308416 ≈0.0766949` stated in the question, based on eq. (35) in the cited 2009 paper and an earlier result of JimB in this context.

To re-emphasize, the motivation behind the use of the transformations was to convert the absolute separability probability inequality into an equality.

Comment: Shamelessly copying @yarchik 's answer (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231201/establish-the-equivalence-of-two-inverse-trigonometric-function-based-formulas/231205#231205), the 3 terms `{{ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]], ArcCot[3 + Sqrt[2]], ArcCot[Sqrt[2]]}` can be written as linear combinations of $\pi$ and $\phi=\cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)$ resulting in $-\frac{15 \left(-2787426131490 \sqrt{2} \phi +1393713065745 \pi  \sqrt{2}-1339642316984\right)}{2 \left(-1990999339560 \sqrt{2} \phi +746624752335 \pi  \sqrt{2}+781862943168 \sqrt{2}-956877309536\right)}$.

Comment: Quite impressive simplification, JimB! LeafCount of 55 vs. original 96. REMARKABLY, FullSimplify applied to the product of your answer here and (as in the question) 29902415923/497664 - 50274109/(512 Sqrt[2]) - (3072529845 π)/(32768 Sqrt[2]) +(1024176615 ArcCos[1/3])/(4096 Sqrt[2]) gives us simply (5 (-669821158492 + 1393713065745 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]]))/5308416 $\approx 0.0766949$, which I suspect (more thinking needed to be sure) should be the result of the 2D integration I request in the question.

Comment: Maybe it's just me but I don't see a complete and compact description of the 2D problem described:  the integrand is only found in a linked post rather than this post (unless I've missed something).

Comment: I've got $\frac{149512079615}{82944}-\frac{754111635}{256 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{46087947675 \pi }{16384 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{15362649225 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{2048 \sqrt{2}}$ for the 2D result.  I'll write up the steps tonight or tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 3):

The answer turns out to be quite simple at the end:

```
(5 (956877309536 + 243 Sqrt[2] (-3217542976 + 1024176615 ArcCos[5983/6561])))/2654208
```

Comment: If `LeafCount` is used as an indicator of simplicity, that's the smallest value yet.  That also demonstrates the trigonometric identity of `ArcCos[5983/6561] == 8 ArcCos[1/3] - 3 \[Pi]`.

Comment: The last sentence of the question is :"The transformation {z -> x - 2 y + 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y]} was used to reduce the original 3D problem to the 2D one." It turns out that if instead one employs {y -> 1/2 (1 - x - z + Sqrt[1 - 2 x - 2 z + 4 x z])}, the resultant integration is speedily carried out, yielding now rather than (5 (956877309536 + 243 Sqrt[2] (-3217542976 + 1024176615 ArcCos[5983/6561])))/2654208 $\approx 0.109748$, the answer (5 (-1339642316984 + 
   1393713065745 Sqrt[2] ArcTan[(4 Sqrt[2])/7]))/5308416 $\approx 0.1533898$. This is exactly equal to  twice the conjecture (continued)

Comment: (5 (-669821158492 + 1393713065745 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]]))/5308416 ≈0.0766949 also put forth in the question, based as indicated on a previous answer of JimB and the formula (35) for the area-volume ratio given in the 2009 paper. This identity can--it would seem--be confirmable through, as seems to have become standard, use of the FindIntegerNullVector command, first employed in this context by yarchik.

Comment: Also, the second transformation seems less problematical in the (probability) sense that the indicated 2D integration, omitting the constraint, yields the real-valued  outcome $\frac{35587695}{4}$, rather than the complex-valued one $-\frac{2391273386563840}{96577}-\frac{516339750748160 i}{96577}$, yielded by the first transformation.

Answer (score 1):

To reiterate (this was not explicit in the original of the question posed), the 2D constrained integration problem I am seeking to solve takes the form

```
Integrate[9081072000 (x - y)^2 (1 - 3 x + 3 y - 4 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 (1 - 3 x +y - 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 (2 y - 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 (-1 + 2 x + 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 (x - 3 y + 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y])^2 Boole[x > y && 3 y > x + 2 Sqrt[y - 2 x y] && 3 x + 4 Sqrt[y - 2 x y] > 1 + 3 y], {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

In the previous answer, the outer integration was first performed, and the denestSqrt procedure of Carl Woll (in his answer to [denestSqrt](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230686/how-do-i-suppress-an-automatic-sign-change-ii)) applied to the univariate result, followed by integration over $y$, yielding the result (LeafCount of 193)

```
-((5 (-1197989196206888748236188141460 + 
461683252327647484985967104198 Sqrt[7] + 
733143027137266392522295640220 Sqrt[2] ArcCsc[3] - 
1759553227963208925524554251975 Sqrt[2]
  ArcSin[1/9 (4 - Sqrt[7])]))/1954710932452630508961792) - (5 (493289889307851856183541978996 + 575808694228213966079710592832 Sqrt[2] -461683252327647484985967104198 Sqrt[7] - 1466024211975381520156897153311360 Sqrt[2] ArcCsc[3/Sqrt[2]] + 1466024211975381520156897153311360 Sqrt[2]ArcCsc[Sqrt[12 - 6 Sqrt[2]]] - 1467783765203344729082421707563335 Sqrt[2]ArcCsc[6 Sqrt[3/(34 + 5 Sqrt[2] - 4 Sqrt[7] - 8 Sqrt[14])]]+578188180294616824015749120 Sqrt[2] ArcSin[Root[1 - 24 #^2 + 72 #^4& , 2, 0]] + 293845361868970757303978720655 Sqrt[2] ArcSin[Root[1 - 24 #^2 + 72 #^4& , 3, 0]]))/1954710932452630508961792
```

Now, we have found that if we first perform the transformation {y -> -(Z^2/(-1 + 2 x))}, the problem is transformed into

```
Integrate[1/y^11 141891750 (y - Z)^2 Z^3 (-2 y + Z)^2 (y - 2 y^2 + 4 y Z - 3 Z^2)^2 (y - 6 y^2 + 8 y Z - 3 Z^2)^2 (-y + 2 y^2 + Z^2)^2 (6 y^2 + Z^2 - y (1 + 4 Z))^2 Boole[y (2 y^2 + Z^2) < y^2 && y (6 y^2 + Z^2 - y (1 + 4 Z)) > 0 && y (y - 6 y^2 + 8 y Z - 3 Z^2) > 0], {y, 0, 1}, {Z, 0, 1/3}]
```

Mathematica now performs the double integration (not now requiring the denestSqrt procedure), yielding (LeafCount of 146)

```
-(1/61046784) 5 (-22008178119328 + 17982847692864 Sqrt[2] + 22896492404940 Sqrt[2] ArcCsc[3] - 45784807319278720 Sqrt[2] ArcCsc[3/Sqrt[2]] +45784807319278720 Sqrt[2] ArcCsc[Sqrt[12 - 6 Sqrt[2]]] - 45839759212195795 Sqrt[2]ArcCsc[6 Sqrt[3/(34 + 5 Sqrt[2] - 4 Sqrt[7] - 8 Sqrt[14])]] - 54951892917075 Sqrt[2] ArcSin[1/9 (4 - Sqrt[7])] +  9158908107195 Sqrt[2] ArcSin[Root[1 - 24 #^2 + 72 #^4& , 3, 0]])
```

However, both results contain the Root command, perhaps impeding possible simplification along the lines of user yarchik--in applying the FindIntegerNullVector command--in his answer to [Establish](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231201/establish-the-equivalence-of-two-inverse-trigonometric-function-based-formulas) .

Comment: `Root[1 - 24 #^2 + 72 #^4 &, 3, 0] // ToRadicals` results in $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\frac{1}{3} \left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)}$.

Comment: And all of the `ArcSin` and `ArcCsc` terms simplify to linear combinations of $\pi$ and `ArcCos[1/3]` using the `FindIntegerNullVector` function.

Comment: Terrific--JimB! Curious as to how a final, simplified form will compare/pertain to my conjecture of (5 (-669821158492 + 1393713065745 Sqrt[2] ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]]))/5308416 ≈0.0766949.

Comment: Using the rule `ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]] -> (\[Pi] - 2 ArcCos[1/3])/2`, then your equation transforms to $-\frac{837276448115}{1327104}+\frac{86031670725 \pi }{65536 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{86031670725 \cos ^{-1}\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)}{32768 \sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: I'm sure I'm being stupid here, JimB--but while I find ArcCot[2 Sqrt[2]] -> (\[Pi] - 2 ArcCos[1/3])/2 in the immediately preceding comment directly copyable into a notebook, the second expression I do not, and I have to proceed piecemeal. If I click on it, a surrounding box appears, which I do not know how to effectively deal with.

Comment: Sorry, I entered that equation as LaTeX so that it would "look nice". Here's the *Mathematica* code:  `-(837276448115/1327104) + (86031670725 \[Pi])/(65536 Sqrt[2]) - (86031670725 ArcCos[1/3])/(32768 Sqrt[2])`.